# Simple doubt about cumulative distribution function property proof

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's fix a probability space $(\Omega,P)$ where $|\Omega| \le \aleph_0$, and a random discrete real variable $X\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

We define the cumulative distribution function $F_X\colon \mathbb{R} \to [0,1] \mid F_X(x)=P(X \le x)$.

I want to prove that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F_X(x)=1$.

My textbook proof goes as follows:

$ $

Let's fix a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid x_n \to +\infty$.

We obviously have $\Omega=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{X \le x_n\}$, where $\{X \le x_n\} \equiv \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \le x_n\}$.

Then $1=P(\Omega)=P(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{X \le x_n\})=\lim_{n \to +\infty} P(X \le x_n)=\lim_{n \to +\infty} F_X(x_n)$.

Then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F_X(x)=1$.

This last line follows from the following theorem:

Let's give a function $f\colon D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=l \iff \forall \,(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq D \mid x_n \to +\infty \quad \lim_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n)=l$.

$ $

All of this is pretty clear to me.

BUT I have a doubt. We have used in this proof the identity:  $P(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{X \le x_n\})=\lim_{n \to +\infty} P(X \le x_n)$, but this is true only if the sequence of events $E_n=\{X \le x_n\}$ is increasing (namely $E_n \subseteq E_{n+1}$), but this is not necessarily the case, since $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not in general increasing.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g$ be a nondecreasing function with $g\leq1$.
Suppose there exists a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x_{n})=1$.
Now, let $\epsilon>0$ and pick $N(\epsilon)$ such that $1-g(x_{n})<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N(\epsilon)$.
Since $g$ is nondecreasing, it follows that $1-g(x)<\epsilon$ whenever $x\geq x_{N(\epsilon)}$.
Therefore, by definition, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=1.$

Returning to your original question, the above suggests that it is sufficient to prove your claim by considering a nondecreasing sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$.
Letting $E_n = \{X\leq x_{n}\}$, the containment $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset \cdots$ holds true and you can conclude, by continuity of measure,
$$
1=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=\mathbb{P}(\cup_{n}E_n)=\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}(E_{n})=\lim_{n}F(x_{n}).
$$